# Is there a polyfill for the CSS3 "initial" property in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, polyfills

Title says it all. I'm wondering if there's some way to get the [initial property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) to work in IE8.

Comment: Is there a particular piece of code that you're stuck on? The best that I can suggest is to look and see what the default UA style is, and manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `initial` is not supported by Internet explorer as confirmed by [Microsoft’s website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh781508.aspx#keywords) (up to IE10 at least).

You could try [a legacy version of this library](https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush/tree/9dc087f64371c772a2aa36284623185e76ed8c50), which seems to support [a significant amount of css property initial values](https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush/blob/9dc087f64371c772a2aa36284623185e76ed8c50/misc/initial-values.ini).

Also, [this website](http://web.archive.org/web/20170122223926/http://www.iecss.com/) has the values that are specific to each version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I know it's not supported by IE. Media Queries aren't supported in IE8 either, but you can use a library like respond.js to add support for them.

Comment: I don't know of any but there is a list of the defaults for internet explorer that I included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why force a meta like

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

so your styles will convert using the latest instead of IE.?

Comment: I tested on IE8 and that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Does not work in IE11 either. Although Edge does work with display:initial